# python using a dictionary for translate() gives me 'TypeError: expected a character buffer object'

Tags: python, replace, translate

why would translate() gives me `TypeError: expected a character buffer object` error when using a dictionary?

```
remap = {
    'with': 'TEXT1',
    'as': 'TEXT2',
    'text_in': 'TEXT3'
    }

s = "with open(loc_path + 'sample_text.txt', 'rb') as text_in:"

ss = s.translate(remap)    
print ss
```

here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\REMAP1.py", line 9, in <module>
    ss = s.translate(remap)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

using replace() works:

```
#ss = s.translate(remap)
#print ss

s = s.replace('with', 'TEXT1')
s = s.replace('as', 'TEXT2')
s = s.replace('text_in', 'TEXT3')
print s
```

output:

```
TEXT1 open(loc_path + 'sample_text.txt', 'rb') TEXT2 TEXT3:
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: What makes you think that `translate` can be used in that way?  Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)?

Comment: are you thristy to downvote? it was used this way in a python cookbook so i wanted to see if it works.

Comment: @jes516: A Python cookbook with invalid code? Don't use that any longer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) (emphasis mine):

> `string.translate(s, table[, deletechars])`
>
> Delete all characters from s that are in `deletechars` (if present), and then translate the characters using `table`, **which must be a 256-character string giving the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal.**

In your code, `remap` does not fulfil this requirement.

Comment: im not sure what that means. is it the syntax that is incorrect or are the values inside the dictionary incorrect?

Comment: @jes516: To my eye, the documentation is very clear. It seems pretty obvious that  *a 256-character string* and *a dictionary* are not the same same thing.

Comment: i understand that. i am confused because i am trying to "correct" the method of using translate() in my code, but i guess there is nothing to correct as it cannot be used with a dictionary, only string?

Comment: @jes516: You can use [`string.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=maketrans#string.maketrans) to make a proper translation table. Basically you pass it two equal length strings defining the character-to-character mapping you want. You can't use it to translate one word to another (which is a multi-character string substitution). Generally you'll probably need to use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=sub#re.sub).

Comment: correct. ive used maketrans and re.sub but i saw an example of translate() being used with a dictionary in a book and i wanted to try it. thank you